# How to use google chrome cookies stored in text file with python get request?

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests, pickle, cookiejar

Sending google chrome cookies directly to python get requests works perfectly fine using the approach below,

```
import requests
import browsercookie
data = requests.get(url, cookies=browsercookie.chrome())
```

But for a very specific use-case, I need to store google chrome cookies in a file and use them (in future) while making a python get request to call as stated above,

I am storing google chrome cookies in a text file as shown below,

```
import browsercookie
import pickle
pickle.dump(browsercookie.chrome()._cookies, open("cookies.pkl","wb"))
```

But I think there is some cookie format issue in the loaded cookies from "cookies.pkl" --
AND THIS DOES NOT WORK...

```
import requests
import browsercookie
import pickle
cj = pickle.load(open("imdb_cookies.pkl", "rb"))
data = requests.get(url, cookies=cj)
```

Error --

```
Error: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I think the cookie dictionary loaded from "cookies.pkl" needs to be converted to ""...

I tried researching a lot but could not find a solution.

If there is any other way where cookies can be stored to files and used in the future, please do let me know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed a different approach and it worked. Instead of using pickle. I used a google chrome extension called cookie.txt. Used that extension to store cookies in cookie.txt. Then used the cookie.txt in the following way with python requests,

```
import http.cookiejar as cookielib
cj = cookielib.MozillaCookieJar('cookies.txt')
cj.load()
data = requests.get(url, cookies=cj)
```